# Дойдет ли запрос, если у сервера отправителя протокол http 1.1 а у получателя 2?

Tags: http

Дойдет ли запрос, если у сервера отправителя протокол http 1.1 а у получателя 2?

Comment: Что такое «сервер отправителя»?

Comment: Сервер, отправляющий запрос

Comment: Отправлять запрос сервер не может в принципе, может только клиент, значит у вас внутри сервера установлен какой-то клиент. Но в любом случае будет просто использоваться меньшая версия, то есть 1.1